# Old value in multiple select option in laravel blade

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my select option

```
<select name="recomemded_food[]" value="" style="width:560px;" multiple class="chosen-select" >
<option value="American Black Bear">American Black Bear</option>
<option value="Asiatic Black Bear">Asiatic Black Bear</option>
<option value="Brown Bear">Brown Bear</option>
<option value="Giant Panda">Giant Panda</option>
</select>
```

And below is my code trying to use the foreach loop to get the array value. but I am receiving the following error:

```
@foreach (explode(',',old('recomemded_food')) as $recomemded_food) 
{{$recomemded_food}}
@endforeach
```

Error Message : explode() expects parameter 2 to be string

Comment: `old('recomemded_food')` is an array in your case.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Just use the Laravel Collective HTML package, then `{!! Form::select('recommnded_food[]', $options, null, ['multiple']) !!}`.

Comment: the select value in view or controller?

Comment: @JilsonThomas in the view

Comment: `<option value="{{ $key }}" {{ (old("recomemded_food") == $key ? "selected":"") }}>{{ $val }}</option>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you pass the select values from Controller:

```
$recommended_foods = ["American Black Bear",
                       "Asiatic Black Bear",
                       "Brown Bear",
                       "Giant Panda"];
```

and In the view:

```
<select required="required" class="form-control" name="recommended_food">
    @foreach ($recommended_foods as $key => $food)
        <option value="{{ $food}}" {{ (old("recommended_food") == $food ? "selected":"") }}>{{ $food }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: If the user submit the form, may be user forgot to fill up another form and pop up error message. Does the old selected value will be there ?

Comment: Yes it will be there.

Comment: The question was asked for multiple selection and the answer you gave will work for single selection. Don't know how you got more votes.

Answer (score 54):

After Playing around a bit I came up with this and it seems to work just splendidly

```
<select name="options[]" id="options" class="form-control" multiple>
    @foreach($settings->includes->get('optionList') as $option)
        <option value="{{ $option->id }}" {{ (collect(old('options'))->contains($option->id)) ? 'selected':'' }}>{{ $option->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I may be 100% wrong in leveraging the collect function but it works fine on many of my tests. I want to say thank you to MPS as it was your example that really made me try this as when there is no data in "recommended_food" you will pull an error because in_array requires an array and will not work well with null so I then came up with the idea of doing something like this.

```
@if (old("options")){{ (in_array($option->id, old("options")) ? "selected":"") }}@endif
```

inline but man that looks ugly to me so long story short I am using the following instead

```
{{ (collect(old('options'))->contains($option->id)) ? 'selected':'' }}
```

Hope this helps others!!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works for Laravel 7.x - I couldn't find a better way online, yet, if any.

Comment: Yapp this is better than accepted answer bcz we couldn't put the old value in controller since the old value is come from old request that from view. Work for me too on laravel 7.x

Comment: Regarding the `in_array` variant not working on first page load(i.e; when no options are selected yet on the `recommended_food` select box, the fix is simple:
 
`{{ in_array($food, old("recommended_food")) ?? [] ? 'selected' : '') }}`

Answer (score 9):

The question was asked for multiple chosen.

Assuming you have a field called designation and you need to choose multiple designation for adding 1 record and the field name is ***forWhom***

**During Add**

You need to add this **{{ (collect(old('forWhom'))->contains($key)) ? 'selected':'' }}**  peace of code to your option tag

which will look like

```
<select id="forWhom" name="forWhom[]" multiple class="form-control chosen">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    @foreach ($desgInfo as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" 
           {{ (collect(old('forWhom'))->contains($key)) ? 'selected':'' }}  />
           {{ $value }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**During Edit**

You need to add

```
{{ (collect(old('forWhom'))->contains($key)) ? 'selected':'' }} 

{{ (in_array($key,$info->forWhom)) ? 'selected' : ''}}
```

which will look like

```
<select id="forWhom" name="forWhom[]" multiple class="form-control chosen">
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
        @foreach ($desgInfo as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}" 
               {{ (collect(old('forWhom'))->contains($key)) ? 'selected':'' }} 
               {{ (in_array($key,$info->forWhom)) ? 'selected' : ''}}  
               />
               {{ $value }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

[Select all selected id's in a multiselect dropdown in laravel 5.4 with harvest chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369072/select-all-selected-ids-in-a-multiselect-dropdown-in-laravel-5-4-with-harvest-c?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Thanks

Comment: this worked for me: `{{ (collect(old('forWhom'))->contains($key)) ? 'selected':'' }} `

Comment: This should be the right answer since it is for multiple select.

Answer (score 4):

For me Jilson Thomas's answer did not work for **multiple select** so I changed it to:

```
{{ in_array($food, old("recommended_food")) ? "selected":"") }}
```

Comment: This does not work on first page load(i.e; when no options are selected yet on the `recommended_food` select box. This works: `{{ in_array($food, old("recommended_food")) ?? [] ? 'selected' : '') }}`

Answer (score 3):

I think the best answer to this question is this below

```
@if(count($categories) > 0)
  @foreach($categories as $category)
      <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ (old('lawyer_fields') == null ? '' : in_array($category->id ,old('lawyer_fields')) ? "selected":"") }}>
                                            {{ $category->name }}
      </option>
  @endforeach
  @else
       <option disabled>بدون انتخاب</option>
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way:

```
<label for="name">Tags</label>
    <select name="tags[]" class="form-control select-tag" multiple>
      @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <option value="{{$tag->id}}" {{in_array($tag->id, old("tags") ?: []) ? "selected": ""}}>{{$tag->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I do, very dynamic.

```
<select id="gender" name="gender">
    <option>Select</option>
        <option value="M">Male</option>
        <option value="F">Female</option>
</select>

<script>
    var currentGender = null;
    for(var i=0; i!=document.querySelector("#gender").querySelectorAll("option").length; i++)
    {
        currentGender = document.querySelector("#gender").querySelectorAll("option")[i];
        if(currentGender.getAttribute("value") == "{{ old("gender") }}")
        {
            currentGender.setAttribute("selected","selected");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was parsing `JSON` data, and was faced with repopulating the multi-select as an `array`, and only wanted one table, and wasn't using `keys` since this `array` was being passed back from the `show` method in the `controller`, so had to supply the values directly on the template, in my case as a crud resource on the `edit.blade.php` template (also on the `create` template).

**This worked for me**,  and was the cleanest I could get it on the view.

```
<select id="recommended_food"   multiple="multiple" size=3 style='height: 100%;' name="recommended_food[]">
    @if ($food->recomemded_food)
      {{ ($val = 'Fries')
        && $chosen = in_array($val, $food->recommended_food)
        ? 'selected':null}}
      <option value="{{$val}}" {{$chosen}}>{{$val}}</option>
      {{ ($val = 'Hot Dogs')
        && $chosen = in_array($val, $food->recommended_food)
        ? 'selected':null}}
      <option value="{{$val}}" {{$chosen}}>{{$val}}</option>
      {{ ($val = 'Hamburgers')
        && $chosen = in_array($val, $food->recommended_food)
        ? 'selected':null}}
      <option value="{{$val}}" {{$chosen}}>{{$val}}</option>
    @endif
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, using `collect(old('roles'))->contains($ role)`

**Ex:**

```php
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="roles" class="form-control-label">Roles</label>
  <select name="roles[]" id="roles" data-placeholder="Choose role..." multiple class="standardSelect">
    <option value="" label="default"></option>
    @foreach($roles as $role)
      <option value="{{ $role }}" {!! (collect(old('roles'))->contains($role)) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' !!}>{{ $role }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases#checked-selected-blade-directives) Documentation

You can now use `@selected` directive like so:

```
  <select name="version">
    @foreach ($product->versions as $version)
        <option value="{{ $version }}" @selected(old('version') == $version)>
            {{ $version }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```