# Select all selected id's in a multiselect dropdown in laravel 5.4 with harvest chosen

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a dropdown called designation, where a user can add some information against multiple designation. If I add 1 record against 3 designation, then I need to select those during validation and edit time also.

Ex: Choosed id's {5,7,8} from [1 to 10].

```
<select id="forWhom" name="forWhom[]" multiple class="form-control chosen">
<option value="">--- Select ---</option>
@foreach ($desgInfo as $key => $value)
<option value="{{ $key }}" {{ old('forWhom',$info->forWhom) == $key ? 'selected' : ''}} />{{ $value }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

After add of those information I store those selected id's in comma(,) separator i.e 5,7,8.

How can I make select this in laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around a bit, I got the result.

Here is the piece of code.

**During Add**

```
<select id="forWhom" name="forWhom[]" multiple class="form-control chosen">
    <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
    @foreach ($desgInfo as $key => $value)
        <option value="{{ $key }}" 
           {{ (collect(old('forWhom'))->contains($key)) ? 'selected':'' }}  />
           {{ $value }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**During Edit**
Suppose you got the result of selected ids in

> **$info->forWhom**

```
<select id="forWhom" name="forWhom[]" multiple class="form-control chosen">
        <option value="">--- Select ---</option>
        @foreach ($desgInfo as $key => $value)
            <option value="{{ $key }}" 
               {{ (collect(old('forWhom'))->contains($key)) ? 'selected':'' }} 
               {{ (in_array($key,$info->forWhom)) ? 'selected' : ''}}  
               />
               {{ $value }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

I hope this will help some one else.