# Old value in multiple select option in laravel 9 blade

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-9

It's about the issue "Old value in multiple select option in laravel blade".

After validation, the selected values are no longer displayed.

```
@dd($values)

   ^ array:8 [▼
  0 => "Auswahl 1"
  1 => "Auswahl 2"
  2 => "Auswahl 3"
  3 => "Auswahl 4"
  4 => "Auswahl 5"
  5 => "Auswahl 6"
  6 => "Auswahl 7"
  7 => "Auswahl 8"
]
```

```
Code:

    <select class='form-select @error($detail_id) is-invalid @enderror' id="{{ $detail_id }}"

            name="{{ $detail_id }}[]" {{ $size }} {{ $multiple }} {{ $disabled }} required="required">

        @foreach ($values as $key => $value)

            <option value="{{ $value }}" {{ (old($detail_id) == $value ? "selected" : "") }}>{{ $value }}</option>

        @endforeach
    </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Old value in multiple select option in laravel blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611945/old-value-in-multiple-select-option-in-laravel-blade)

Comment: The answer there suggests something like: `(collect(old($detail_id))->contains($value)) ? 'selected' : ''`

Answer (score 0):

do this , it's work on my projects

```php
{{ (collect(old($detail_id))->contains($value)) ? 'selected':'' }}
```