# How to pre-select select statements in Laravel

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a select statement with a large number of options to select. I am retrieving all of the options from my back-end and filling them in. However I would also like to select an option, which I also pass in from my backend. My code is as follows:

```
<tr class="table_row">
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="TB1_instructions_course[]" id="course" required="" value='{{$info['userInfo']['courses'][$i]}}'>
            <option value="">Course</option>
            @foreach($info['staticInfo']['courses'] as $course) //pull in static data
            <option>{{$course['course']}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </td>
<tr>
```

Now the text field works perfectly and populates it accordingly, but I am unable to select the appropriate option in my select input. Any help? Can I do this without using jQuery or javascript?

Comment: `<select>` elements don't have a `value` attribute in HTML, but their `<option>` children do.

Comment: @TimLewis is it possible to have an option pre selected?

Comment: you have to add `selected` attribute to `<option>`. Some simple research into how `<select>` tag works would have answered this yourself.

Comment: @charlietfl yea that occurred to me but my options are in a for each loop :/

Comment: so? You check if their value matches the one you want in the loop

Comment: Or you use https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html and let it handle it for you.

Comment: My most upvoted answer is about this exact issue, so check it out if it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148274/define-the-selected-option-with-the-old-input-in-laravel-blade/29148608#29148608 (although the use case and syntax is a bit different due to an older version of Laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the option that have the matched value like :

```
<td>
    <select class="form-control" name="TB1_instructions_course[]" id="course">
        <option value="">Course</option>
        @foreach($info['staticInfo']['courses'] as $course) 
            @if ( $course['course'] == $info['userInfo']['courses'][$i] )
                <option value="{{$course['course']}}" selected="selected">{{$course['course']}}</option>
            @else
                <option value="{{$course['course']}}">{{$course['course']}}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
```

**NOTE:** The option should have a `value` attribute (added in my example).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly, didn't think about this approach! THANKS! Will mark my question as answered