# Select field Old value cannot be displayed in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation, laravel-6

I'm having a user registration form with a select field, When ever I get an error on the form user redirected to the form and display the previously entered values

I able to display old values for the text fields but I am finding it difficult to display old values for the select field,

My select field as follows,

```
<select id="app-subdomainsuffix"  class="form-control @error('subDomainSuffix') is-invalid @enderror" name="subDomainSuffix" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="">- {{ __('sentence.Select domains') }} -</option>
                                <option value="test.site"  >TEST.SITE</option>
                            </select>
```

I'm using laravel 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need value for each option and i don't see any value for your first option.
Then you need a logic to check if the option was selected and assign "selected Attribute" to HTML  :

```
<select id="app-subdomainsuffix"  class="form-control @error('subDomainSuffix') is-invalid @enderror" name="subDomainSuffix" aria-required="true">
                                <option value="value1" @if(old('subDomainSuffix') == "value1") selected @endif >- {{ __('sentence.Select domains') }} -</option>
                                <option value="test.site" @if(old('subDomainSuffix') == "test.site") selected @endif >TEST.SITE</option>
                            </select>
```

Above example can just demonstrate how to select the option, but for cleaner code you better come with array of option as mentioned in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148274/define-the-selected-option-with-the-old-input-in-laravel-blade) .

Comment: tried, still getting no error or not working either, but in the form 'subDomainSuffix') == "value1")  shows in red color..

Comment: May i ask what is validation rules for "subDomainSuffix" ?

Comment: yup, it's 'subDomainSuffix' => 'required',

Comment: write this code above <select> tag to check what you receive <pre>{{ var_dump(old('subDomainSuffix')) }}</pre>

Comment: it gives, string(9) "test.site"

Comment: And still doesn't select "test.site" option when page is loaded ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211190/discussion-between-volka-dimitrev-and-alpha6572).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<option value="test.site"  {{ (old("subDomainSuffix") == 'test.site' ? "selected":"") }}>TEST.SITE</option>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it