# I want to fill my form with data from database using redirect in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Im new to laravel, my question is - is there any way to retrieve data from redirect() without using with() function, i have a view with  values filled from database returned from controller. based on the value selected, i want to fill the form

Controller-

```
public function getSearchData()
{        
    return view("welcome",["data"=>User::all()]);
}


public function getSearchDetail(Request $request)
{        
    $searchdata = User::where("email",$request->user)->first();

    return redirect("/")->with(["searchdata"=>$searchdata]);
}
```

Route -

```
Route::get("/",[UserController::class,"getSearchData"]);

Route::get("/search",[UserController::class,"getSearchDetail"]);
```

View -

```
<form action="/search" method="GET">
    <select name="user" id="user">
        @isset($data)
        @foreach ($data as $detail)
        <option value="{{$detail->email}}">{{$detail->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        @endisset
    </select>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<form action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
    <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="">
</form>
```

only way i know how to fill the form is using session(), like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="@if (session('searchdata'))
            {{ session('searchdata')->name }}
        @endif">
```

and this is not good, i don't want my single `<input />` to be that long, is there any solution to this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#old-input and https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old if you want it to be shorter.

Comment: @Rwd you mean fill the <select> with values from old()?
i didn't find how to anywhere, can you show me an example how to do that?

Comment: No, you'd keep the data for the select as it is now. You'd just need to say whether the option has been selected or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148274/define-the-selected-option-with-the-old-input-in-laravel-blade

Comment: @Rwd I don't understand, only when i use redirect will the <select> values remain, i don't want it to show what i selected before redirect, i want to fill the remaining form with the values i get from the redirect without using if and session to each <input>

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you did because you asked about the select in your previous comment. In that case, just use `old` to set the value of your inputs.

Comment: @Rwd let me explain,
 first when the view is loaded, return view("welcome",["data"=>User::all()]);
 <select> is filled and all the <input>s will be EMPTY,
 so after i select the value and click submit, it'll be redirected back to SAME VIEW from controller with data, using with(),
 if i want to fill the value to all the <input>s i have to use if and session for each <input> in the view.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured was going on. The way to handle this in Laravel is to use flash it to the session and then use something like `old`. `old` is effectively just going to replace the `if` and `session` you already have.

Comment: @Rwd with() is same as flash() , its not working, i tried to flash data i got from db, and old() didnt work, still need session()